# how to get several values from input and display the largest value from standard output?

Tags: python

I have a standard output like below:

```
seventy-five 0.050
states 0.719
drainage-basin 0.037
scotland 0.037
reading 0.123
thirty-eight 0.000
almost 0.037
rhine 0.000
proper 0.037
contrary 0.087
```

How can I define a method to input several strings like "states" and it will return its value "0.719" and its conclusion;

```
Enter query words, one per line. Blank line to end: 
proper
almost
rhine
```

then they return:

```
states 0.719
almost 0.037
rhine 0.000
largest value is states
```

otherwise return "item not in list". As I am a beginner, I don't really know how to deal with standard output. I have tried:

```
result = input("Enter query words, one per line. Blank line to end: ")

if result in STD:
    the_result = STD[result]
else:
    print("item not in list")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a dictionary `STD` to store your data. Read the user inputs and store each input and it's corresponding data as key and value in a dictionary `the_result`.

Finally, the key corresponding to the largest value in dictionary `the_result` is the largest item.

```
import operator

STD = {'seventy-five': 0.050,
'states': 0.719,
'drainage-basin': 0.037,
'scotland': 0.037,
'reading': 0.123,
'thirty-eight': 0.000,
'almost': 0.037,
'rhine': 0.000,
'proper': 0.037,
'contrary': 0.087}

print("Enter query words, one per line. Blank line to end: ")
result = []
while True:
    line = input()
    if line:
        result.append(line)
    else:
        break

the_result = {}
for each in result:
    if each in STD:
        the_result.update({each: STD[each]})
        print("{} {}".format(each, STD[each]))
    else:
        print("{} not in list".format(each))

print("largest value is {}".format(max(the_result.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]))
```